# Netgear Administratrive distance

Tags: wireless

Not sure if this is the right stackexchange forum though

I am using Netgear WNR1000v2 running firmware version 1.1.2.58.

Open authentication is enabled, so no password is required, and only used for tests.

Whenever I am close from the AP, mobile devices and laptops connect directly, however when getting away from the router, the SSID appears to have security implemented as it asks for a password and cannot connect anymore although we are in the range of the router.

I know on Cisco devices, there is such thing as administrative distance, does this exist as well on Netgear devices?